# Exclude directories with find command and executing a script on other directories

Tags: bash, find

I currently have a directory structure that I need to be able to roll through each of 100 or so directories and run a script on them individually while excluding this check on a handful of other directories.

This is what I have been using in the past:

```
find ./OTHER/ -maxdepth 2 -wholename '*_*/*.txt' -execdir /files/bin/other_process {} +
```

I would like to exclude certain directories from this check and have not found a sufficient answer to this problem.

This has been my best attempt (or two) at the problem:

```
find ./OTHER/ \( -path ./OTHER/X???_EXCLUDE_THIS -prune -o -path ./OTHER/X???_IGNORE_THIS -prune -o \) -type d \(-name *_*/*.txt \) -execdir /files/bin/other_process {} +
```

I get:

```
find: paths must precede expression  ./OTHER/A101_EXCLUDE_THIS/
```

This is the return that I get on nearly every variation that I have used.

Comment: Can't test at the moment, but try `find ./OTHER/ \( -path './OTHER/X???_EXCLUDE_THIS' -o '-path ./OTHER/X???_IGNORE_THIS'\) -prune -o  -path '*_*/*.txt'  -execdir echo /files/bin/other_process {} +` And remove the `echo` if that works

Answer (score 0):

> This has been my best attempt (or two) at the problem:
>
> ```
> find ./OTHER/ \( -path ./OTHER/X???_EXCLUDE_THIS -prune -o -path ./OTHER/X???_IGNORE_THIS -prune -o \) -type d \(-name *_*/*.txt \) -execdir /files/bin/other_process {} +
> ```

Errors in this attempt:

- `\(-name`: There must be a space after `\(`.
- `-name *_*/*.txt`: `-name` is for base of file name; use `-path` here.
- `*_*/*.txt`: You should quote such patterns to prevent expansion by the shell.
- `-o \)`: `-o` does not belong at the end of an expression; you mean `\) -o`. But you don't need parentheses here.
- `-type d`: Since you want to find *regular files* `*.txt`, you must not look for a **d**irectory.

With those errors corrected, it works:

```
find ./OTHER/ -path './OTHER/X???_EXCLUDE_THIS' -prune -o -path './OTHER/X???_IGNORE_THIS' -prune -o -path '*_*/*.txt' -execdir echo {} +
```